# kdbq OAuth 1.0 implementation

Tags: oauth, kdb

Fellow kdb Mortals/Gods :)

I am currently stuck on implementing the OAuth 1.0 protocol in kdb. Any help will be appreciated!!

I have an api that uses OAuth1.0 authentication, but kdb doesn't seem to have any straight forward implication for this

For background:
[image]

**Step 1. Get request token** 
All I have to do is a `POST` request to the request token endpoint `/oauth/token/request`

with headers (described above)

```
Authorization: OAuth oauth_consumer_key="<api-username>",oauth_signature_method="HMAC-SHA1",oauth_timestamp="<timestamp>",oauth_nonce="<nonce>",oauth_version="1.0",oauth_signature="<signature>"
Content-Type: application/json
```

What I am having difficulty is in constructing `oauth_nonce` and `oauth_signature` in kdb.

From my understanding regarding these parameters from https://consumingrestapis.github.io/chapter-4/4.1-oauth-1.0.html#fn:3

1. It seems that `oauth_nonce` is just a random string that is unique across requests, the way I am implementing this is by `base64` encoding `.z.p`. That way I will always get a new string because the timestamp is unique.
2. What I am stuck at now is how to generate `oauth_signature`? The encoder/decoder for the signature is `HMAC-SHA1`, I have been using `q` internal `.Q.sha1` encoder to encode the signature string that I came up with the following (from above link)
   [image]

Not sure if I am missing something here or there is a better/simpler implementation of OAuth 1.0 for kdb that already exists and I am just not aware of it. But any help here would be super appreciated.

Thank you!!